# Duplicate column name error using UNION query on the world table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a full join on the Mysql built in World database's three tables by the country code. I want to count the number of row returned.

Here is what I wrote:

```
    SELECT * From city 
 LEFT JOIN country 
        ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
 LEFT JOIN countrylanguage 
        ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
     UNION
    SELECT * from city 
RIGHT JOIN country 
        ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
RIGHT JOIN countrylanguage 
        ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode;
```

This returned `30671` rows. 
If I wrap the `COUNT(*)` clause outside,

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT * from city 
 LEFT JOIN country 
        ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
 LEFT JOIN countrylanguage 
        ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
     UNION
    SELECT * from city 
RIGHT JOIN country 
        ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
RIGHT JOIN countrylanguage 
        ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode) AS B;
```

it rises 
`Error Code: 1060. Duplicate column name 'Name'`.

I try to do it the other way:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) from (
    SELECT c1.* from city AS c1
 LEFT JOIN country AS co1
        ON c1.CountryCode = co1.Code
 LEFT JOIN countrylanguage AS cl1
        ON co1.Code = cl1.CountryCode 
     UNION 
    SELECT c2.* from city AS c2
RIGHT JOIN country AS co2
        ON c2.CountryCode = co2.Code
RIGHT JOIN countrylanguage AS cl2
        ON co2.Code = cl2.CountryCode) AS B;
```

Only has `4080` rows.

I am not sure which one is the correct way?

Thank you

Comment: Use a UNION ALL statement instead of UNION if you want to count duplicate rows. A UNION will return only return distinct rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, sub-queries cannot contain two columns with same name, otherwise you get error 1060.

The workaround is to replace `*` with the complete list of columns, aliasing when necessary:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT
               city.ID, city.Name, city.CountryCode, city.District, city.Population,
               country.Code, country.Name AS country_Name, country.Continent, country.Region, country.SurfaceArea, country.IndepYear, country.Population AS country_Population, country.LifeExpectancy, country.GNP, country.GNPOld, country.LocalName, country.GovernmentForm, country.HeadOfState, country.Capital, country.Code2,
               countrylanguage.CountryCode AS countrylanguage_CountryCode, countrylanguage.Language, countrylanguage.IsOfficial, countrylanguage.Percentage
          FROM city
     LEFT JOIN country
```

However, you are not interested in all columns, just enough to get the number of distinct combinations. So  your query simplifies to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT city.ID, country.Code, countrylanguage.CountryCode, countrylanguage.Language From city
     LEFT JOIN country
            ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
     LEFT JOIN countrylanguage
            ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
         UNION
        SELECT city.ID, country.Code, countrylanguage.CountryCode, countrylanguage.Language From city
    RIGHT JOIN country
            ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
    RIGHT JOIN countrylanguage
            ON country.Code = countrylanguage.CountryCode
) AS B;

-- 30671
```

Answer (score 0):

You get error

> Duplicate column name 'Name'

because in your joins are multiple times column ***name***

In normal query it is not a problem but with `count(*)` it matters. You must provide aliases for *name* columns, something like

```
city.name AS city_name
country.name AS country_name
countrylanguage.name AS countrylanguage_name
```

See also this [Duplicate column name on JOIN in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23560526/duplicate-column-name-on-join-in-mysql).

Alternatively if you need only count you could remove the unneeded columns from select, for example changing

```
SELECT *
```

to

```
SELECT id -- or any appropriate column
```

and then get `count(id)` or `count(*)`.